# How to get a path assuming you don't know the path using dots slash?

Tags: wordpress, path, relative-path

I have this path

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/imagen.jpg
```

I want to convert that path 
something as it

```
../../../imagen.jpg
```

( or using `~` or `./` or other way assuming you don't know the folders)

I am working with Wordpress.

Comment: What is your end goal? Where are you using this?

Comment: well as you see this has 2015/10 and this is on localhost, when this was moved to a hosting i'll need change it (in all I have used it ) include the "localhost" word, then using dot and slash (I believe), change it would not be necesary

Comment: Whoops, that's not what I meant. Are you using it in a CSS file? In the WP editor? In a PHP template? Elsewhere?

Comment: Then you can't do what you're asking...The best you could do is `/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/imagen.jpg` (without the origin). Better question: *why* do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the wordpress site is the base of your domain, you would simple write /wp-content/uploads/.....

Generally, when you are in the content editor, it is my understanding that the /wp-content/ folder is rendered to be in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a plugin that will let you put in the path via shortcode, such as [URL & Path Shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-path-shortcodes/)

Then, if the path to your image is:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/imagen.jpg
```

Just change it to this:

```
[wp_upload_dir path="imagen.jpg"]
```

Comment: Oh wait... I just took a look at this plugin and it doesn't work correctly with sub-directories.  You would need to turn off this option first.  Just go to Settings > Media and uncheck "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders".  You would then need to move your image into the main /wp-content/uploads/ directory